# Spring MVC, call Controller if the word mentioned in the RequestMapping matches in the URL

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it possible to call the Controller if the executed URL contains the word mentioned in the @RequestMapping of the respective Controller?

Here is my code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/employee","/nonemployee","/temp"})
public class EmployeeController {

   @Autowired
   EmployeeService service;

   @RequestMapping("/add")
   public ModelAndView employee() {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("emp/add", "command", new Employee());
      return modelAndView;
   }

   @RequestMapping("/employees")
   public ModelAndView getEmployeeList() {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/emp/employees", "list", service.getEmployeeList());
      return modelAndView;
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/create")
   public String createEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee, ModelMap model) {
      service.newEmployee(employee);
      model.addAttribute("name", employee.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", employee.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", employee.getId());
      return "/emp/create";
   }
}
```

Using the above code with `@RequestMapping({"/employee","/nonemployee","/temp"})` and `@RequestMapping("/employees")`, we can call the following urls, to list values:

1. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/employee/employees`
2. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/nonemployee/employees`
3. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/temp/employees`

On observing closely, we can see the matching word ***emp*** within all the three words/values passed to the RequestMapping. So, what I am looking for is the way using which the execution of Controller is occurred, if the URL contains the word ***emp***.

On execution of the following URLs, list of values must be returned by the same method (`getEmployeeList()`), but without passing multiple or all the values to RequestMapping Annotation:

1. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/employee/employees`
2. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/nonemployee/employees`
3. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/temp/employees`
4. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/exempt/employees`
5. `http://localhost:8080/Spring/attempt/employees`

Comment: You can try specifying a regular expression and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you Request Mapping to -

```
               @RequestMapping("/*emp*")
```

This should work for what you want to do.